# Find ListView, DataPager, ObjectDataSource in Different Content Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, objectdatasource, findcontrol

I find few things as frustrating as trying to find my ASP .NET controls in different content controls. For layout, I need to place a ListView in one content control and a DataPager and ObjectDataSource in a different content control.

```
<asp:Content ID="cPagedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPagedContent" runat="Server">
<asp:MultiView ID="mvPagedContent" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="mvPagedContentDefault" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvPagedContent" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="hp-post-even">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="<%# Eval("QuickLink") %>">
                            <%# Eval("Title") %></a></h2>
                    <p>
                        <%# Eval("Html") %></p>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <div class="hp-post">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="<%# Eval("QuickLink") %>">
                            <%# Eval("Title") %></a></h2>
                    <p>
                        <%# Eval("Html") %></p>
                </div>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="mvPagedContentTaxonomy" runat="server">
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="mvPagedContentSearch" runat="server">
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cAboveFooter" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphAboveFooter" runat="Server">
<asp:MultiView ID="mvPager" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="mvPagerDefault" runat="server">
        <asp:DataPager ID="dpContentPager" runat="server"
            PageSize="6">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" FirstPageText="[First]" PreviousPageText="[Prev]"
                    ShowNextPageButton="false" ShowLastPageButton="false" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                    ShowFirstPageButton="true" />
                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="4" />
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                    NextPageText="[Next]" LastPageText="[Last]" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                    ShowLastPageButton="true" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsContent" runat="server" EnablePaging="true" MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows"
            SelectCountMethod="GetContentCount" SelectMethod="GetContent" StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="mvPagerTaxonomy" runat="server">
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>
```

In my C# file, I can locate the ListView control. But I can't seem to find the DataPager and ObjectDataSource to associate with the ListView.

Here is a snippet from Page_Load.

```
    ListView listView;
    ObjectDataSource objectDataSource;
    DataPager dataPager;

    listView = mvPagedContentDefault.Controls[0].FindControl("lvPagedContent") as  ListView;

    objectDataSource = mvPagerDefault.Controls[0].FindControl("odsContent") as ObjectDataSource;
    objectDataSource.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
    listView.DataSourceID = objectDataSource.ID;

    dataPager = mvPagerDefault.Controls[0].FindControl("dpContentPager") as DataPager;
    dataPager.PagedControlID = listView.ID;
```

Any ideas on how I might find these suckers? It's driving me a bit nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand where the problem is. You have a reference to the `MultiView` control, haven't you? It has a property [`Views`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.views.aspx) which returns a collection of `View` controls in the MultiView control. The `DataPager` and `ObjectDataSource` are both in the first view.

```
var dpContentPager = (DataPager)mvPager.Views[0].FindControl("dpContentPager");
var odsContent = (ObjectDataSource)mvPager.Views[0].FindControl("odsContent");
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.pagedcontrolid.aspx):

> Use the PagedControlID property to specify the ID of the control that
>   contains the data that will be paged by the DataPager control. **The
>   specified control** must implement the IPageableItemContainer interface
>   and **must use the same naming container as the DataPager control**. An
>   example of a control that you can specify is the ListView control.

You can try to create a custom pager that inherits from `DataPager` which overrides `FindPageableItemContainer` to find the ListView even if it's in a different NamingContainer.

Have a look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1458342.aspx/1

Comment: @williamdnapier: The ListView and the DataPager are in different NamingContainers. That's not allowed(see my edit).

Comment: @williamdnapier: Have you seen that i've just edited the answer again? So you either need to create your custom DataPager or change your view.

Comment: @williamdnapier: If that "commenting out" approach does not work(what i'm afraid), you could try to use  a [`recursive FindControl approach`](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl) in `FindPageableItemContainer` starting from a given container control. Of course that works only if there's really only one control with ID `lvPagedContent`.